# Implement bookmarking in scorm using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, moodle, moodle-api, scorm1.2

I'm using moodle 3.2 and scorm 1.2
I'm trying to implement bookmark feature in my scorm package containing multiple SCOs.

Here's the code I'm using -

```
function SCOonload(){
SCOInitialize();

var bookmark = LMSGetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location");

if (bookmark){
url = bookmark;
}
jumpToPage(url);
}
```

I'm very new to scorm and javascript. What should I write in jumpToPage so that it opens the bookmarked location?

Thanks.

Comment: Please help anyone??

Answer (score 0):

### Couple warnings -

If you aren't using AJAX or a iframe/frameset, then JavaScript will initialize on each page which means you have to re-connect the SCORM Runtime API.  You would not want any type of unload event to fire terminating the SCO prematurely.  I have seen cases where the LMS adds extra values to the URL of the SCO Presented and when you change the URL things go sideways (just as a general warning).

LMS's support single page SCO's with their own TOC (Table of Contents) and navigation commonly. And when you get into doing multiple pages within the SCO you get to manage the navigation. So when you bundle multiple pages you'll just need to manage either the IFRAME load of individual pages or a AJAX load of pages.  This has also traditionally been accomplished with other plugin technologies like Flash, Java etc...

Can you just change the page without AJAX and a Frame?  Sure, but I'd caution about how the LMS can behave.  They some times have their own unload listeners and monitor the SCORM Runtime.

Comment: Cool! I'm still confused. I guess I'll try again to convey my question - I have multiple html pages and each html page acts as a single page chapter (SCO) in scorm course. Now, what approach do I take? Iframe/frameset or ajax or none of these??

Comment: https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki/Single-Pages-Managed-by-LMS-Navigation  Check that out. See if it helps.